# Difficulty parsing .xml file from smarkets

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have a (huge) .xml file which is more or less a variation of the below snippet which I managed to get loaded with Vim. What I have been trying to do is find where the child tag `market` has a slug name of 'correct score', and then I need list all the information in the below contract, or a method to iterate through the below contract.

Can someone help me out? I have went through all the basic examples, but my file is unlike the online examples, and it's 2am...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#__________________________________
tree = ET.parse('get_this.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    print "Match Names", child.attrib['name']
print


rows = root.findall('.//market')

for child in rows:
    if child.attrib['slug'] == 'correct-score':
        print child.attrib
        print child.attrib['id']

        #when I have found the id and correct score market, how do I work with the data below it?
```

## The file snippet.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<odds timestamp="2018-09-28T00:50:15Z">
 <event date="2018-09-28" id="960747" name="Babelsberg vs. ZFC Meuselwitz" 
  parent="/sport/football/germany-regionalliga-2018-2019" 
  parent_name="Germany Regionalliga" parent_slug="/sport/football/germany-regionalliga-2018-2019" 
  state="upcoming" time="17:00:00" 
  type="Football match" 
  url="/sport/football/germany-regionalliga/2018/09/28/sv-babelsberg-03-vs-zfc-meuselwitz">

    <market id="7777534" slug="winner" traded_volume="0" winners="1">
      <contract id="26245385" name="Draw" slug="draw">
        <bids>
          <price backers_stake="364.54" decimal="4.9" liability="1421.56" percent="20.41"/>
        </bids>
        <offers>
          <price backers_stake="449.21" decimal="3.35" liability="191.15" percent="29.85"/>
        </offers>
      </contract>
      <contract id="26245384" name="ZFC Meuselwitz" slug="away">
        <bids>
          <price backers_stake="360.35" decimal="5.3" liability="1549.28" percent="18.87"/>
        </bids>
        <offers>
          <price backers_stake="507.56" decimal="3.55" liability="199.05" percent="28.17"/>
        </offers>
      </contract>
      <contract id="26245383" name="Babelsberg" slug="home">
        <bids>
          <price backers_stake="361.58" decimal="2.20" liability="433.98" percent="45.45"/>
        </bids>
        <offers>
          <price backers_stake="146.07" decimal="1.80" liability="182.62" percent="55.56"/>
        </offers>
      </contract>
    </market>

    <market id="7777540" slug="correct-score" traded_volume="4" winners="1">
      <contract id="26245430" name="Any other draw" slug="any-other-draw">
        <bids>
          <price backers_stake="0.00" decimal="10000" liability="13.24" percent="0.01"/>
        </bids>
        <offers>
          <price backers_stake="13.68" decimal="44" liability="0.32" percent="2.27"/>
        </offers>
      </contract>
      <contract id="26245429" name="Any other away win" slug="any-other-away-win">
        <bids>
          <price backers_stake="0.00" decimal="100" liability="0.24" percent="1.0"/>
        </bids>
        <offers>
          <price backers_stake="0.15" decimal="17.0" liability="0.01" percent="5.88"/>
        </offers>
      </contract>
      <contract id="26245428" name="Any other home win" slug="any-other-home-win">
        <bids>
          <price backers_stake="0.01" decimal="28" liability="0.18" percent="3.57"/>
        </bids>
        <offers>
          <price backers_stake="0.22" decimal="11.0" liability="0.02" percent="9.09"/>
        </offers>
      </contract>
      <contract id="26245427" name="3 - 3" slug="3-3">
        <bids>
          <price backers_stake="0.00" decimal="10000" liability="23.56" percent="0.01"/>
        </bids>
        <offers>
          <price backers_stake="5.46" decimal="30" liability="0.19" percent="3.33"/>
        </offers>
      </contract>
      <contract id="26245426" name="3 - 2" slug="3-2">
        <bids>
          <price backers_stake="0.00" decimal="10000" liability="28.01" percent="0.01"/>
        </bids>
        <offers>
          <price backers_stake="3.15" decimal="20.0" liability="0.17" percent="5.0"/>
        </offers>
      </contract>
    </market>
  </event>
</odds>
```

Comment: your current solution (appears) to work fine ... whats your question  (in otherwords what output are you getting vs what output are you expecting)

Comment: @Joran Beasley  the question is how do I go from isolating any particular market to working wth only the contracts involved with that market?

Comment: child.getchildren()

Comment: @Joran Beasley right, it's just a library thing then...will have a good look in morning. Thanks for pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want complete information under market tag with slug name as correct score, try with the below code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('./sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.findall('.//market'):
    if child.attrib['slug'] == 'correct-score':
        for ele in child.iter():
            print(ele.tag,ele.attrib)
```

i took your xml file in sample.xml, Hope it will help you

Comment: The job is already completed Lakshmi, but thank you for posting regardless.